# Fetch stored Objects in EhCache

Tags: java, eclipse, ehcache

Please help me to understand and fetch the stored objects from EhCache.
Am using Eclipse with Tomcat Web Server.
Am using ehcache-core.2.5.0.jar

```
Execution Flow 1:(No Problem)
1,Start Eclipse and Run Applicaton
2,Call StoreServlet.java with value 10   --- this works
3,Call FetchServlet.java                 --- this works
4,Call StoreServlet.java with value 20   --- this works
5,Call FetchServlet.java                 --- this works
6,Call ShutdownServlet.java              --- this works
```

Even If I try the same with After restarting `Eclipse` it works,
If I try to restart my `System(Windows)` and do the below steps,Am getting no objects from stored Disk,but in Disk **.data file** contains all the stored values.

```
Execution Flow 2:(araises Problem)
1,Restart System,Start Eclipse and Run Applicaton
2,Call FetchServlet.java  --- no exception but objects count in cache is 0.
```

**Code :**

```
CacheHelper.java :
public class CacheHelper {
private static Cache profitCache = null;
private static CacheManager manager = null;
private static CacheManager getManager()
{
    if(manager == null)
    {
        Configuration cacheManagerConfig = new Configuration();
        DiskStoreConfiguration disk =new DiskStoreConfiguration();
        disk.setPath("E:/Leo-Softwares/DataStore_ehCache");
        cacheManagerConfig.addDiskStore(disk);
        manager = CacheManager.create(cacheManagerConfig);
    }
    return manager;
}
private static void getCache()
{
    CacheConfiguration cacheconfig = new CacheConfiguration("Profit",1000);
    cacheconfig.memoryStoreEvictionPolicy(MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy.LFU)
    .eternal(true)
    .diskPersistent(true);
    profitCache = new Cache(cacheconfig);
    getManager().addCache(profitCache); 
}
public static void insert(Profit pro)
{
    if(profitCache == null)
    {
        getCache();
    }
    Element element = new Element(pro.getId(),pro);
    profitCache.put(element);
}
public static List getAllkeys()
{
    if(profitCache == null)
    {
        getCache();
    }
    return profitCache.getKeys();
}
public static Profit get(Object obj)
{
    if(profitCache == null)
    {
        getCache();
    }
    return (Profit)profitCache.get(obj).getObjectValue();   
}
public static void shutdown()
{
    if(manager != null)
    {
        manager.shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

**StoreServlet.java**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
{
    int i = request.getParameter("IVAL")!=null
            ?Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IVAL")):1000;
            System.out.println("IVAL:"+i);
    int j =i;
    int k = i +10;
    for(  j=i;j<k;j++)
    {
        Profit pro = new Profit();
        pro.setId(j);
        pro.setAmt(j+" AMT");
        CacheHelper.insert(pro);

    }
 System.out.println("j:::"+j);
}
```

**FetchServlet.java**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
{
    List<Object> lst = CacheHelper.getAllkeys();
    Iterator<Object> iter = lst.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        Object obj = iter.next();
        System.out.println("key:"+obj);
        Profit pro = CacheHelper.get(obj);      
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("i in fetch@@@:"+i);
}
```

**ShutdownServelet.java**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
{
    CacheHelper.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: How is your Cache Configured?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke Thanks for your reply.I don't have any xml.Am doing all the configuration in getManager() and getCache() methods posted in Question.